EF Core call with filtering, paging, sorting and sorting direction
I need to write an EF query which will return a list of Event objects but also include child objects (User) and also use filtering on some properties in both parent and child objects, use paging, use sorting and sorting direction (ascending/descending) - all based on provided parameters.
I wrote an early version of the query and it does partially work and does return some values. The problem here is:

I can't select sorting direction as that requires calling either OrderBy() or OrderByDescending() conditionally.
for ordering, I cannot use properties inside the child objects as that requires providing it straight in the query unconditionally (I'd need to write OrderBy(prop => EF.Property<object>(prop.User, sortBy))).

The query:
    public async Task<List<EventModel>> GetEventsPagedFilteredSorted(
        int page,
        int itemsPerPage,
        string filterText,
        string sortBy,
        bool ascending,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
var query = _db.Event
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(e => e.User)
    .Where(e => e.User.UserName.Contains(filterText)
        || e.EventCode.Contains(filterText))
    .OrderBy(prop => EF.Property<object>(prop, sortBy))
    .Skip(page * itemsPerPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage)
    .ProjectToType<EventModel>()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
    ;

return result;
}

I then tried to split the query up into smaller pieces so that I can then split it up even more and introduce conditions but now the result is completely empty for some reason.
var query = _db.Event
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(e => e.User)
    .Where(e => e.User.UserName.Contains(filterText)
        || e.EventCode.Contains(filterText))
    .OrderBy(prop => EF.Property<object>(prop, sortBy))
    .Skip(page * itemsPerPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage)
    ;

var result = await query
    .ProjectToType<EventModel>()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

return result;

The Event class:
public class Event 
{
    [Key]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

How can I write a query with all the conditions I need?
UPDATE:
After some hints from the answers here, I'm down to this piece of code which already works as I wanted but there is still some code duplication that I would like to get rid of (the code providing properties for ordering):
            var query = _db.Event
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(e => e.User)
                ;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
                query = (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Entities.Event, Entities.User>)
                    query
                    .Where(e => e.User.UserName.Contains(filterText) || e.EventCode.Contains(filterText))
                    ;

            IOrderedQueryable<Entities.Event> queryOrdered;
            if (ascending)
                queryOrdered =
                    query
                    .OrderBy(e => EF.Property<object>(SortByContainsUser(sortBy) ? e.User : e, sortBy))
                    ;
            else
                queryOrdered =
                    query
                    .OrderByDescending(e => EF.Property<object>(SortByContainsUser(sortBy) ? e.User : e, sortBy))
                    ;

            queryOrdered = (IOrderedQueryable<Event>)
                queryOrdered
                    .Skip(page * itemsPerPage)
                    .Take(itemsPerPage);

            var result = await queryOrdered.ToListAsync();
            var resultAdapted = result.Select(e => e.Adapt<EventModel>()).ToList();
            return resultAdapted;

The SortByContainsUser() method:
bool SortByContainsUser(string sortBy) => sortBy.Contains("User") || sortBy.Contains("user");


Add the calls one by one instead of chaining them. if(ascending){ query=query.OrderBy(..); } else {query=query.OrderByDescending(...);}. Haven't you asked the same thing already? _ is used to discard parameters in many cases so few (if any) use it as an actual parameter name.

There's no ProjectToType either, that's what Select does. AutoMapper has ProjectTo to generate the query automatically using only the fields specified in a DTO, but in the end it still generates a Select(e->new EventModel{ EventID=e.EventId,....}). It's that Select that gets translated to SQL

Adding the calls one by one is exactly what I'm saying isn't working for me - I get 0 results. ProjectToType is a Mapster method. Yes, I did ask a similar question but no-one gave a solution so I rephrased it and posted again.

No, you didn't understand the answer, used the wrong code and never updated the question with the failing code.  You're already adding the calls one by one. Every call in that chain is applied to the previous IQueryable and returns a new one. That new one may implement different interfaces. You can still store them in variables with the correct type. This isn't about LINQ, it's about basic C# and types

"How can I write a query with all the conditions I need?" - What are all the conditions you need? Are the ones mentioned in the question a complete list of them?

I'd actually suggest splitting the question in two parts: 1. How to conditionally order and 2. How to order by related enttity props. As those are two disjoint problems to solve and some users may know how to solve either one of them but maybe not both. It would also better follow SO policy "one question per problem".

The question's split produces wrong results. Skip and Take must be applied after ordering, otherwise the query will try to order a random page's result instead of returning the first page based on the desired order. Order.Skip.Take generates ORDER BY x1 OFFSET @o FETCH NEXT @page. Skip.Take.Order results in SELECT .. FROM (SELECT x1 ... OFFSET FETCH ) tmp ORDER BY tmp.x1

For conditional sorting, move the conditional aspect outside of the Linq query expression. For example if you want to sort by a particular property:
var query = _db.Event
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.User.UserName.Contains(filterText)
        || e.EventCode.Contains(filterText));

switch(sortBy)
{
   case "User.UserName":
      if(sortDescending) 
         query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.User.UserName):
      else
         query = query.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName);
      break;
   // add applicable conditions.
}
var result = await query.ProjectToType<EventModel>()
    .Skip(page * itemsPerPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

return result;

Without seeing the details of how you are passing your sort conditions to identify what you want to sort by and sort direction it's hard to provide an exact example, but the above should get you moving in the right direction. You can essentially extrapolate the column and direction however you need from whatever is passed in to get something you can assess the property and whether an ascending or descending sort should be applied.
You cannot embed custom calls into linq expressions, and even where you can embed conditional code it is better to externalize it from the query so that the query only includes the extra filters etc. if they are needed rather than running a more complex SQL statement that embeds conditional checks.
Additionally, when using projection with Mapster's ProjectToType(), Automapper's .ProjectTo() or .Select() you do not need to eager load entities to use in projections or conditions/filters. EF will resolve those automatically as they are referenced. Eager loading (.Include()) is only needed when you want to retrieve an entity and its related entities.
Note: Also ensure if you are using the *Async() flavours of methods like .ToListAsync() that you are awaiting the call. Your example doesn't look to have been complete/compile-able but something to check.

Why dont you start with a query like:
var query = _db.Event
.AsNoTracking()
.Include(e => e.User)
.Where(e => e.User.UserName.Contains(filterText)
    || e.EventCode.Contains(filterText));

Then add the sorting conditionally, where sortBy is some property name:
var sortBy = someCondition ? "Username" : "Timestamp";

if (ascending)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(prop => EF.Property<object>(prop, sortBy));
}
else
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(prop => EF.Property<object>(prop, sortBy));
}

I know nothing about ProjectToType, if it's using Expression<Func<Event, EventModel>>, then it could work:
public static QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEventModel> ProjectToType<TEventModel>(this IQueryable<Event> query)
    {
        //use some mapper that works with Expression<Func<Event, TEventModel>> to map to the new type, maybe AutoMapper
        return query.ProjectTo<TEventModel>();
    }
}

Then call:
var result = await query
.ProjectToType<EventModel>()
.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

And, if you want to log the generated query first:
Console.WriteLine(query.ToQueryString());


I removed ProjectToType and it still gives me 0 results for some reason. Will try removing more stuff.

@Val use ToQueryString to see what the actual SQL query is.
